# Problem Linking Bigquery with Google Sheet file: I can only read the first sheet

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery Console I created a new external table that is linked to a Google Sheet file.

Even if I choose the proper sheet's link there is no way I can pull that information into my table: I can only reach the first one.

I am creating my file choosing 'Drive' as a Source and copying everything that comes next to my FILE_ID:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit#gid=SHEET_ID

With this example I would introduce something like this: FILE_ID/edit#gid=SHEET_ID

But I can't get the specified sheet I need.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

From the BigQuery console you should not need to specify the sheet in the URI.
See the following example where the sheet is specified in the sheet range

[image: Example table definition]

For reference see the example in this section of the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive#creating_and_querying_a_permanent_external_table